# No DNS for Windows Server Core

Tags: active-directory, internal-dns, windows-server-2019

I have set up an Active Directory with DNS Servers on the Domain Controller. I have already joined Computers and DNS works for all machines, even those that are not in the domain. I wanted to setup another Server, a Windows Server 2019 Core, and join it into the Domain. But it cant resolve the Domain name, even tho it can ping all DNS Servers and there are no additional firewall rules in place. Has anyone an idea what the problem is, or what i can do to fix this?

Comment: What is your DNS server set to in the settings of the network adapter? Try doing `nslookup` from the core server to the AD DC

Comment: it is set to the ip address of the dc. it also says so when is try the command `nslookup corp.example.com`

Comment: what is the output of the `nslookup` command?

Comment: ´Server:  [192.168.1.1]
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.` it works on every other machine: > server 192.168.1.1
Standardserver:  [192.168.1.1]
Address:  192.168.1.1

> corp.example.com
Server:  [192.168.1.1]
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    corp.example.com
Addresses:  192.168.1.1
          192.168.1.2

> exit

Comment: You do not accidentally have an IP address conflict? Did you try doing `nslookup` to a different DNS server? What's the output there? Also, if your DNS server is connected to more than 1 network card, if I remember right, there is  setting in the dns server or zone where you can specify on which network the DNS server listens and anwers.

Comment: seems like the problem was, that the centos router was blocking dns traffic.... what a rookie error D: Thanks for the help anyways :)